# use sparse matrices with jax

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, jax

I´m trying to optimize a code which heavily utilizes operations with sparse matrices, and tried using jax as follows

```
import jax.scipy as jsp
from jax.scipy import sparse
```

nevertheless, when trying to convert create a sparse matrix from another matrix as follows

```
sHamil_ONE= sparse.csr_matrix(Hamil_multi_pol)
```

I got this message

```
AttributeError: module 'jax.scipy.sparse' has no attribute 'csr_matrix'
```

So, what should I do here?

Comment: Where's your documentation?

Answer (score 4):

JAX does not provide wrappers for `scipy.sparse` matrix APIs, but `jax.experimental.sparse` provides some experimental support for sparse arrays that are compatible with `jit`, `vmap`, autodiff, and other JAX transformations.

Usage would look something like this:

```py
from jax.experimental import sparse

Hamil_ONE = sparse.BCOO.fromdense(Hamil_multi_pol)
```

You can read more here: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.experimental.sparse.html

Comment: Do these sparse representations work with JAX sharding (optimised collective communication)?

Answer (score 0):

It says that the `jax.scipy.sparse` module does not have a `csr_matrix` function. Instead, you can use `jax.numpy`:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp

# create a matrix with some zeros
data = jnp.array([1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4])
indixs = jnp.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1])
indptr = jnp.array([0, 2, 3, 6])

# create the csr_matrix (2x3)
csr_matrix = jsp.sparse.csr_matrix((data, indixs, indptr), shape=(2, 3))
```

Comment: This approach may work in the simplest cases, but scipy sparse structures are generally not compatible with JAX arrays and JAX transformations like JIT, vmap, and automatic differentiation. See my answer for another approach.